# How to decrement and increment the value, and display value

Tags: javascript, html

If statement with decrement, and display value

I am trying to increment & decrement the value from `id="wordcount"` and add the value with existing value in `id="running-summary-total"`. As you increase the value in `id="wordcountl"` also increment the value `id="running-summary-total"` and also decrement and add and display the value in `id="running-summary-total"`

```
<input class="form-control input-number" type="number" name="costcount" 
       value="" min="1" max="100000000000" id="costcount" 
       onchange="changequantity();"  data-cart-item-unique-id="2d8ed345d3c6ce2221b9638e26e955b5" data-ajax-url="">
```

```
<div class="col-sm-5 x-total"><input type="text" readonly="readonly" name="total" id="total" value="0.00"></div>
```

**Script**

```
<script>
function changequantity() {
    var z = document.getElementById("costcount").value;
    console.log(z)

    if (++z) {
        var t = document.getElementById("total").value;
        var wc = parseFloat(t) + parseFloat(4);
        document.getElementById("total").value =  wc;
    } else if (--z) {
        var t = document.getElementById("total").value;
        var wc = parseFloat(t) - parseFloat(4);
        document.getElementById("total").value =  wc;
    }
</Script>
```

Incrementing the value is working fine but NOW when one decrement the value it instead increment it. How do I solve the issue?

Comment: Unless the value of `z` is -1, `if(++z)` always evaluates to true, and hence the value is always incremented. else block is never executed. What is the condition based on which you need to decrement the value?

Comment: @AmalK i need to decrement the value with same value that was incremented with, which is --4

Comment: You have used an if-else block, where strictly only one block runs. Either it will increment or it will decrement. If you want both to happen one after another, remove the else. And what exactly is z?

Comment: What's your end goal here? Is "4" needing to be hardcoded?

Answer (score 1):

Your topmost `if` block will only execute in exactly 1 condition -- and that's if `z = -1` initially.

`if (++z) {` will increment `z` and then check if it is non-zero. In all cases except when it was originally -1 that will be true.

Since `} else if (--z) {` is an `else` it will ONLY happen when the `if` block above does NOT happen.

BUT, we know that the top `if` will only NOT happen when z = 0. But `if (--z) {` will, as above, ONLY happen when z is originally 1, which is impossible.

So there are no conditions which will combine to cause the second block in the else to execute.

I'm not super clear on the exact end-goal or why z is being incremented and decremented in place in this way, but I'm hoping the explanation on why it is happening may help.